# mat-checkbox and ngIf in angular 5 is not working

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material, angular5, angular-ng-if

I have this code to hide and show a piece of content every time a checkbox is ticked and unticked. However, it is not working.

```
<mat-checkbox ngModel="checked" ngInit="checked=true">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
            <div *ngIf="checked">
                    <mat-radio-group formControlName="contactSupport">
                            <mat-radio-button value="Low">Low</mat-radio-button>
                            <mat-radio-button value="Normal">Normal</mat-radio-button>
                            <mat-radio-button value="high">high</mat-radio-button>
                            <mat-radio-button value="none">None</mat-radio-button>
                    </mat-radio-group>

            </div>
```

Comment: By the way, `ngInit` **does not exist**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is use 2 way binding

Change this :

```
ngModel="checked"
```

to

```
[(ngModel)]="checked"
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-checked)**